# How to block attributes from being used in java

Tags: java

Basically I would like to know if there is a way to "disable" an attribute within a block after a certain point.

For example check the following scenario:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  for(int j=i+5;j<50;j++){

      //from here until end of the block I want to make sure I don't use **i** anymore.
      print(j*5+i);  //I want this line to produce compiler error
  }
}
```

Don't get me wrong I understand it is a bad programming, but I still can't help but to use i,j,k,h as attributes. and sometimes I make a mistake by misplacing the attributes in wrong places.

Comment: Structure your code so that you only have access to the values you should have - create methods, use final variables and divide your code into small parts.

Comment: Put the code that should not be able to use `i` in a separate method. A separate method has its own distinct local variable scope.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?! Your reasoning does not make sense.

Comment: @Smutje yes I understand that. This is certainly good way of programming. however, I need to write codes for mathematical formulas, and using loops within loops within loops... is very natural . also using attributes such as i,j,k makes it very similar to the actual formulas. thus structuring my code takes a very long time

Comment: don't trust yourself? it is simple, don't use i or j.

Comment: @bigdestroyer well, that's certainly the case. but if you have to write such codes every day you realize how hard it is :D.

Answer (score 4):

Call a method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 5; j < 50; j++) {
    doSomething();
  }
}

...

private void doSomething() {
  // Woot, no i and no j!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense to anybody. You need to divide it into functions with good names so that anyone can understand what your program is doing without comments around the code or getting mixed up with variables.

Here's an example for the code you have posted:

```
public void printNumberTimes5(int number) {
      print(number*5);
}
```

But don't stop there, make it obvious what the loop is doing too:

```
public void printSomeNumbers(int someNumber) {
  for(int j=someNumber+5;j<50;j++){
     printNumberTimes5(j);
  }
}
```

And again:

```
   public void printSomeNumbers_repeat(int repeat) {
       for(int i=0;i<repeat;i++){
           printSomeNumbers(i);
       }
   }
```

I don't really know what you're doing but renaming the function to what you're supposed to be doing would make it clear.

Remember: each function should only have one job.

Finally, give `i` and `j` real names so that you understand what those numbers do and don't mix them up.

Comment: I know all the problems regarding this code. as I said I have to program mathematical models. my problem isn't that I don't know how to make a good program, my problem is to produce it fast. especially in mathematical algorithms.

Comment: @nafas Actually, your question was about not mixing up variables so that's what I answered. Only now you're saying you know how to do that but you want to write code fast.

Comment: well my question  specifically was how to block attributes from being used. The reason I wanted to do that so I reduce mistakes within my program as I use variable such as i,j,k(which come from my mathematical formulas). I understand your code would certainly help to reduce such mistakes, but this approach would be slow to use. I just rather to focus not to make a mistake rather than use slow approach.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to obtain this in java, is by using [scope](http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm). Make sure that the variables are in different scopes and then you don't have access to it. A good guideline to follow is to split your logic in various small methods, this way you'll ensure the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since so many of answers talk about why this is a bad idea, so I won't repeat it.

One solution that comes to my mind is to use an counter object. Whenever you want a particular counter to go out of scope, set that to `null`. If you use it after this point, a `Null pointer access` warning is shown (at least in eclipse. I suspect other IDEs should also have this feature. Not sure whether `javac` generates a warning).

```
public class DisappearingVariables {

    public static class Counter {
        int i = 0;
        public Counter() {
        }
        public void inc() {
            i++;
        }
        public int get() {
            return i;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(Counter i = new Counter(), oi = i; i.get() < 10; i = oi, i.inc()) {
            System.out.println("i = " + i.get());
            i = null;
            i.inc(); // This line gets a warning
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a NullPointerException, even if you leave out the i.inc inside the for-loop?

Comment: Still a good starting point. Maybe though it would be better to have a lock() method on Counter rather then nulling-out the reference.

Comment: The idea is to provide a warning. Having a lock() method does not provide the warning.

Comment: At runtime NPE will be thrown for `i.inc()`. According to OP, the need is to avoid using `i` after a point.

Comment: In your situation the `i = null` also acts as a delayed `break;` as the  `i`-`for`-loop can't evaluate the condition for the next loop. But additionally to the break a NPE is thrown which may lead to lose of the result. I thought OP wanted to hide the variable from the rest of the block, not from the `for`-header and the next iteration

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations in order of preference:

1. Use meaningful variable-names. Maybe `i` isn't as good as e.g. `row`, ...
2. Use functions to group operations and also reduce the variables they can access. This can also lead to a point where repeating operations can easily be reused.
3. Use a custom counter-object like this one

   ```
   /**
    * Created for http://stackoverflow.com/q/25423743/1266906
    */
   public class ObliviousLoops {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           for(LockableCounter i = new LockableCounter(0); i.getValue() < 42; i.unlock().increment()) {
               System.out.println("A-loop:" + i.getValue());
               i.lock();
               // No access, everything is fine
           }
           for(LockableCounter i = new LockableCounter(0); i.getValue() < 42; i.unlock().increment()) {
               System.out.println("B-loop1:" + i.getValue());
               i.lock();
               // Next statement will throw an Exception
               System.out.println("B-loop2:" + i.getValue());
           }
       }

       static class LockableCounter {
           private long value;
           private boolean locked;

           LockableCounter(long value) {
               this.value = value;
           }

           public LockableCounter lock() {
               this.locked = true;
               return this;
           }

           public LockableCounter unlock() {
               this.locked = false;
               return this;
           }

           public long getValue() {
               if(locked) {
                   throw new IllegalStateException("Accessing locked counter");
               }
               return value;
           }

           public void increment() {
               if(locked) {
                   throw new IllegalStateException("Accessing locked counter");
               }
               value++;
           }

           @Override
           public String toString() {
               if(locked) {
                   throw new IllegalStateException("Accessing locked counter");
               }
               return String.valueOf(value);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   the most obvious draw-backs of the last solution is a less fluent handling of the value, less ways to optimize the operations for the compiler, ... in practice you may even want to replace the `LockableCounter` by something different, once you are sure you calculations are written as desired to speed things up.
4. Use Java 8's lambda-function to build something behaving similar to `for`-loops where you can `null`-out the counter for the rest of the cycle (actually this is a variant of #2)

   ```
   import java.util.function.Consumer;
   import java.util.function.Function;
   import java.util.function.Predicate;

   /**
    * Created for http://stackoverflow.com/q/25423743/1266906
    */
   public class LambdaLoops {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           iterate(0, 42, (i) -> {
               System.out.println("A-loop:" + (i + 0));
               i = null;
           });
           iterate(0, (i) -> i < 42, (i) -> ++i, (i) -> {
               System.out.println("B-loop:" + (i + 0));
               i = null;
           });
           iterate(0, (i) -> i < 42, (i) -> {
               System.out.println("C-loop1:" + (i + 0));
               i = null;
               // Next statement will not throw an Exception
               System.out.println("C-loop2:" + i);
               // Next statement will throw an Exception
               System.out.println("C-loop3:" + (i + 0));
           });
       }

       static void iterate(Integer initial, Integer limit, Consumer<? super Integer> function) {
           for (Integer i = initial; i < limit; i++) {
               function.accept(i);
           }
       }

       static void iterate(Integer initial, Predicate<? super Integer> when, Consumer<? super Integer> function) {
           for (Integer i = initial; when.test(i); i++) {
               function.accept(i);
           }
       }

       static <T> void iterate(T initial, Predicate<? super T> when, Function<? super T, ? extends T> increment, Consumer<? super T> function) {
           for (T i = initial; when.test(i); i = increment.apply(i)) {
               function.accept(i);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   as in #3 this will most likely lead to decreased performance, but has the advantage, that your IDE might alert you, that `i` will always be `null`. This should however be easier to optimize be inlining than #3 as there is no additional `boolean` involved. If and when the JIT does inlining is however hard to guess.